# Angular and linked drop down lists not holding data

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am attempting to make my view contain 3 dropdown lists and a submit button. I have figured out how to not show a dropdown until it contains data. I've figured out how to get it to load upon change of the previous dropdown. However, I have a couple of issues. Here is the code and then I will explain the issues:

The view:

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-show="$parent.loggedin">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lawType">Type of Law</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="lawType" ng-change="getCourthouse();" data-ng-model="typeoflaw">
                    <option value="0" selected>--Select a Type of Law--</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="type in typeoflaw" value="{{ type.LitigationCode}}">{{ type.LitigationType }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group" data-ng-show="courtHouse.length">
                <label for="courtHouse">Courthouse</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="courtHouse" data-ng-model="courtHouse" ng-change="getCourtroom();">
                    <option ng-repeat="bldg in courtHouse track by $index" value="{{ bldg.Loc_ID }}">{{ bldg.Loc_Name }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group" data-ng-show="courtRoom.length" data-ng-model="courtRoom">
                <label for="courtRoom">Department</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="courtRoom">
                    <option ng-repeat="room in courtRoom" value="{{ room.CourtRoom }}">{{ room.CourtRoom }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="favorite-button">
                <button class="btn  btn-primary pull-left">Add Favorite</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The controller:

```
JBenchApp.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$filter', 'UserService', 
  function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $filter, UserService) {
          // Get the preferences information
      /**UserService.loadType()
      .then(function (lawtypes) {
          $scope.typeoflaw = lawtypes;
      });**/



      $http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/Litigation').success(function (response) {
          $scope.typeoflaw = response;
      });

      //$scope.courtHouse = [{ "Loc_ID": "0", "Loc_Name": "-- Select a Type of Law to Get Courthouse List --" }];
      //$scope.courtHouse = [];
      //$scope.courtRoom = [];

      $scope.getCourthouse = function () {
          var e = document.getElementById("lawType");
          $scope.typeoflawId = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
          console.log($scope.typeoflawId);
          $http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/CourtDept/' + $scope.typeoflawId).success(function (response) {
              $scope.courtHouse = response;

          }).error(function (status, data) {
              console.log("error trapped");
          });
      }

      $scope.getCourtroom = function () {
          var e = document.getElementById("courtHouse");
          $scope.courtHouseId = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
          console.log($scope.courtHouseId);
          $http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/CourtDept/' + $scope.typeoflawId + "/" + $scope.courtHouseId).success(function (response) {
              $scope.courtRoom = response;

          }).error(function (status, data) {
              console.log("error trapped");
          });
      }

      $scope.SavePreferences = function () {

      };

  }]);
```

The issues:

1. When the first dropdown, Type of Law, loads, it does not have "--Select a type of law--" selected as I requested in the markup. In fact, there is just an empty entry that is above the "select a type of law" and it is selected by default. How can I make the initial entry in the list be selected at load?

   2. When the first dropdown is changed (a selection is made) it loads the second dropdown, but the first dropdown is then empty other than the blank row mentioned previously and the "select a type of law" entry. How do I make it hold the data that was there and show the selected item correctly?
   3. When the second dropdown is changed, it loads the third drop down, but has the same problem as the first one...it empties itself and it also doesn't show the selection the user makes. How do I make it not empty itself and still show the selection the user made?

thanks!

Comment: You don't need to prefix angular directives with "data-" so `data-ng-model` can just be `ng-model`.

Comment: Also, getting elements from a form by ID in javascript is bad practice for angular applications. Just bind the data you need using `ng-model` and access it directly through  `$scope`. That's the main thing that makes angular worth using.

Comment: I had resolved a similar question with ng-options directly on select. Can you to create a jsbin/jsfiddle with your issue?

Comment: @TomSlick how do I get the selected value of a dropdown from the ng-model and $scope?

Comment: if your `ng-model` is "typeoflaw" it'd be `$scope.typeoflaw`. You should look at `ng-options` though for dropdowns

Comment: Whichever variable you bind using `ng-model`, in this case `typeOfLaw`, will be accessible through `$scope` as a property: `$scope.typeOfLaw`

Comment: OK, so changing to using $scope.typeoflaw to get the selected item has worked just fine. However, i still have the issues.mentioned previously...the dropdowns empty themselves upon selection and they don't (of course) have the ability to display what was selected as the dropdown becomes empty).

Comment: Like @JoaozitoPolo says, if you create a jsFiddle  we can help you troubleshoot it.

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo if you put the ng-options as the answer I can give you the credit for it. That solved the problem. I will post more when finished, but the problem is solved and it was ng-options that solved it

Comment: Please you put your solution code as an answer, and marks as resolved. It's valid too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ultimately solved the issue.

In the view:

```
<div ng-controller="UserCtrl">
    <div class="row" ng-show="$parent.loggedin">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="lawType">Select a Type of Law</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="lawType" name="lawType" ng-change="getCourthouse();" ng-model="typeoflaw.LitigationType" ng-options="typeoflaw.LitigationType for typeoflaw in typeoflaw track by typeoflaw.LitigationCode" required>
                    <option value="">--Select a Type of Law--</option>
                   <!-- <option value="0" selected>--Select a Type of Law--</option>
                    <option ng-repeat="type in typeoflaw" value="{{ type.LitigationCode}}">{{ type.LitigationType }}</option>-->
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="courtHouse.length">
                <label for="courtHouse">Select a Courthouse</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="courtHouse" name="courtHouse" ng-model="courtHouse.Loc_ID" ng-change="getCourtroom();" ng-options="courtHouse.Loc_Name for courtHouse in courtHouse track by courtHouse.Loc_Name" required>
                    <option value="">--Select a Courthouse--</option>
                    <!--<option ng-repeat="bldg in courtHouse track by $index" value="{{ bldg.Loc_ID }}">{{ bldg.Loc_Name }}</option>-->
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="form-group" ng-show="courtRoom.length">
                <label for="courtRoom">Select a Department</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="courtRoom" name="courtRoom" ng-model="courtRoom.CourtRoom" ng-options="courtRoom.CourtRoom for courtRoom in courtRoom track by courtRoom.CourtRoom" required>
                    <option value="">--Select a Department--</option>
                    <!-- <option ng-repeat="room in courtRoom" value="{{ room.CourtRoom }}">{{ room.CourtRoom }}</option>-->
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="favorite-button" ng-show="courtRoom.length">
                <button class="btn  btn-primary pull-left" ng-click="SavePreferences();">Add Favorite</button>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-show="userPreferences.length">
        <div class="col-sm-12 favorite-header">
            <h2>Your Saved Favorites</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12 favorite-filter">
            <input type="text" ng-model="query" placeholder="Filter your favorites list" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-show="userPreferences.length">
        <div class="col-sm-3 favorite-column-title">
            Courthouse
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 favorite-column-title">
            Department
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 favorite-column-title">
            Type of Law
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 favorite-column-title">
            Default
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" ng-show="userPreferences.length" ng-model="userPreferences" ng-repeat-start="userPreference in userPreferences | filter:query | orderBy: ['LocName', 'CourtRoom']">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <span class="get-path" ng-click="setPathValues(userPreference.LitigationCode, userPreference.LocID, userPreference.CourtRoom);">{{ userPreference.LocName }} ({{ userPreference.CourtRoom}})</span>
</div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ userPreference.CourtRoom}}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            {{ userPreference.LitigationType }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <span ng-if="showDefaultIcon(userPreference.IsDefault);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok green-check" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="This is your default favorite and it cannot be deleted. Please mark another favorite as your default before attempting to delete this one." tooltip></span>
            <span ng-if="!showDefaultIcon(userPreference.IsDefault);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty red-star" ng-click="setAsDefault(userPreference.PreferenceID, userPreference.LitigationCode, userPreference.LocID, userPreference.CourtRoom);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Mark this favorite as your default." tooltip></span>
            <span ng-if="!showDefaultIcon(userPreference.IsDefault);" class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove delete-icon" ng-click="deletePreference(userPreference.PreferenceID);" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete this favorite." tooltip></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat-end></div>
</div>
```

In the controller:

```
JBenchApp.controller('UserCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http', '$filter', '$window', 'HoldState', 
  function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, $filter, $window, HoldState) {


      $scope.isDefault = false;


      $http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/Litigation').success(function (response) {
          $scope.typeoflaw = response;
      });

      $scope.getCourthouse = function () {
          $scope.typeoflawId = $scope.typeoflaw.LitigationType;
          console.log($scope.typeoflawId);
          $scope.courtRoom = [];
          $http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/CourtDept/' + $scope.typeoflawId.LitigationCode).success(function (response) {
              $scope.courtHouse = response;

          }).error(function (status, data) {
              console.log("error trapped");
          });
      }

      $scope.getCourtroom = function () {
          var e = document.getElementById("courtHouse");
          $scope.courtHouseId = $scope.courtHouse.Loc_ID;
          console.log($scope.courtHouseId);
          $http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/CourtDept/' + $scope.typeoflawId.LitigationCode + "/" + $scope.courtHouseId.Loc_ID).success(function (response) {
              $scope.courtRoom = response;

          }).error(function (status, data) {
              console.log("error trapped");
          });
      }

      $scope.LoadPreferences = function () {

          $http.get('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/UserPreference/dpeng').success(function (response) {
              $scope.userPreferences = response;
          }).error(function (status, data) {
              console.log("error trapped");
          });
      }

      $scope.SavePreferences = function () {
          $scope.userid = 'dpeng';
          $scope.departmentNumber = $scope.courtRoom.CourtRoom;
          $scope.newPreference = {
              "PreferenceID": "0",
              "UserID": $scope.userid,
              "LocID": $scope.courtHouseId.Loc_ID,
              "CourtRoom": $scope.departmentNumber.CourtRoom,
              "IsDefault": $scope.isDefault,
              "LitigationCode": $scope.typeoflawId.LitigationCode
          };
          $http({
              method: 'POST',
              url: 'http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/UserPreference/Post',
              data: $scope.newPreference,
              headers: {
                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
              }
          }).then(function(response) {
              LoadPreferences();
              console.log(response);
          }, function(response) {
              console.log(response.status + " -- " + response.data + " -- " + response.statusText);
          });
      }

      $scope.showDefaultIcon = function (theStatus){
          return theStatus;
      }

      $scope.showSetAsDefaultIcon = function (theStatus) {
          if (theStatus) {
              return false;
          } else {
              return true;
          }
      }

      $scope.setAsDefault = function (prefId, LitCode, LocID, Dept) {
          alert("setAsDefault function is called")
          var data = {
              "LitigationCode": LitCode,
              "LocID": LocID,
              "CourtRoom": Dept,
              "IsDefault": true
          };

          $http.put(' http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/UserPreference/Put/' + prefId, data)
          .then(function (response) {
              LoadPreferences();
              console.log(response);
          }, function (response) {
              console.log(response.status + " -- " + response.data + " -- " + response.statusText);
          });
      }

      $scope.deletePreference = function (prefId) {
          $http.delete('http://10.34.34.46/BenchViewServices/api/UserPreference/Delete/' + prefId);
          LoadPreferences();
      }

      $scope.setPathValues = function (LawType, Bldg, Dept) {
          HoldState.setTypeOfLaw(LawType);
          HoldState.setCourthouse(Bldg);
          HoldState.setDepartment(Dept);
          var a = HoldState.getTypeOfLaw();
          var b = HoldState.getCourthouse();
          var c = HoldState.getDepartment();
          //alert('Law: ' + a + ' Courthouse: ' + b + ' Department: ' + c);
          $window.location.href = 'calendar';
      }

      $scope.LoadPreferences();

  }]);
```

The key is ng-options:

```
ng-model="courtHouse.Loc_ID" " ng-options="courtHouse.Loc_Name for courtHouse in courtHouse track by courtHouse.Loc_Name"
```

When I set things up like this the 3 dropdowns sync up perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

the way i solved the problem of passing data between one or more controllers was by using services.
so this was an example of a service

```
var NameService = function () {
    var service = this;
    service.property= value;
    service.getProperty = function () {
        return property;
    }
};
ngapp.service('NameService', NameService);
```

the cool thing about it is you can inject your service in your controller

```
appcontroller.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'NameService'];
$.ajaxSetup({
    async: false
});
var NameCtrl = function ($scope, $http, NameService) {
    var Property = NameService.Property;
    $scope.update = function () {
        NameService.Property= $scope.Properties.selectedProperty.PropertyId;
    }
};
appcontroller.controller('NameCtrl', NameCtrl);
```

Comment: This particular question is not about passing data between controllers, but this idea may be eventually what I need.Can you address the three issues raised or explain how your answer DOES address the 3 issues in my question?

Comment: i apologize i didn't see those questions
<div class="col-xs-2">
                        <select class="form-control" data-ng-model="Property.selectedProperty" data-ng-options="property.Name for properties in Properties" 
                            data-ng-change="update()"> // where you will update the property and will be used to fire the event to update the second drop down
                        </select>
                    </div>

Comment: in order to initialize with a default value
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="Properties.selectedProperty" data-ng-options="property.Name for property in Properties" 
                                data-ng-change="update()" data-ng-init="property.Name = 'Select a'">
                                                       
                       </select>

Comment: $scope.update = function () {
        PropertyService.property= $scope.Properties.selectedProperty..Name;
    }